# Ubuntu I/O or read only filesystem errors and crash with Firewire (IEEE1394)

Tags: crash, firewire

I have a Macbook pro 2011 with Ubuntu 21.04.

I back up the Ubuntu partition to an external hard disk HGST 1TB 5400 rpm built in May 2017, through the Firewire or IEEE1394 800 interface and an external enclosure,

```
mac2011-linux% lsmod|grep firewire
firewire_sbp2          24576  3
firewire_ohci          45056  0
firewire_core          69632  2 firewire_ohci,firewire_sbp2
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
```

with rsync version 3.2.3 protocol version 31 (delivered with Ubuntu).

I have just bought a new enclosure: after copying many files normally, it makes input output error and finally freezes the system (displays but does not respond to mouse, keyboard, `ping`).

The log obtained with `journalctl -k -b -1`:

```
Oct 11 17:23:33 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: sbp2_scsi_abort
Oct 11 17:23:34 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
Oct 11 17:23:36 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
Oct 11 17:23:38 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: rediscovered device fw1
Oct 11 17:23:39 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: error status: 0:9
Oct 11 17:23:39 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: failed to reconnect
Oct 11 17:23:40 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: logged in to LUN 0000 (0 retries)
Oct 11 17:23:40 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: status write for unknown ORB
Oct 11 17:24:10 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: sbp2_scsi_abort
Oct 11 17:24:11 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
Oct 11 17:24:13 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: phy config: new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
Oct 11 17:24:15 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_core 0000:04:00.0: rediscovered device fw1
Oct 11 17:24:16 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: error status: 0:9
Oct 11 17:24:16 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: failed to reconnect
Oct 11 17:24:16 mac2011-linux kernel: firewire_sbp2 fw1.0: logged in to LUN 0000 (0 retries)
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=67s
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 61 bf 93 78 00 02 00 00
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1639945080 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1564304632 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400735, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400736, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400737, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1639945592 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1463993832 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 64 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 60861885, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1564304664 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400739, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400740, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400741, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400742, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1639946104 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1564304712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400745, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 73400746, lost async page write
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1463994344 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 50 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1564304760 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x103000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Aborting journal on device sdb4-8.
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1639946616 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 10 writing to inode 20449433 starting block 204993464)
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm kworker/u8:4: Detected aborted journal
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sdb4-8.
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): ext4_journal_check_start:83: comm rsync: Detected aborted journal
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): Remounting filesystem read-only
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss!  (inode 20449433, error -30)
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855727
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855728
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855729
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855730
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855731
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855732
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855733
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855734
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855735
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sdb4, logical block 82855736
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): htree_dirblock_to_tree:993: inode #20316727: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316727: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316727: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316727: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316727: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316727: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316730: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316730: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:47 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #20316730: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: print_req_error: 3981 callbacks suppressed
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1576952952 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error: 868 callbacks suppressed
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 977098752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 977098752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: buffer_io_error: 4647 callbacks suppressed
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs: 857 callbacks suppressed
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1576952952 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 977098752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 977098752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1576952952 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 977098752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 977098752 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x3800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1576952952 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblockw
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb4): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #18744014: comm rsync: reading directory lblock 0
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb4, logical block 0, lost sync page write
Oct 11 17:24:55 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb4): I/O error while writing superblock
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
Oct 11 17:24:58 mac2011-linux kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb4): dx_probe:757: inode #24248322: lblock 0: comm rsync: error -5 reading directory block
```

With the same harware, I can backup a Mac OS partition with Mac OS X. (This excludes for example a cable problem.)

Although Firewire normally does not require external supply, I have used the external supply provided with the enclosure, at no avail.

After repairing or reformatting the target volume, I have read only filesystem error and system crash.

I happen to have another enclosure of the same model (Storeva AluICE), same problem.

I have further narrowed down the problem: as the backup partition is also bootable, I have tried to boot it with the old and new enclosures.  Only the new enclosure fails with I/O errors and kernel panic.  Consequently, `rsync` is not involved.

Moreover I have repeated the problem on a Crucial SSD MX500 1 TB, which excludes a storage device problem.

Booting Mac OS El Capitan on the same devices goes smoothly.

Booting Ubuntu on the same devices connected through the internal SATA no problem.

See also [Ubuntu read-only errors writing to Macbook pro in target disk mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336008/ubuntu-read-only-errors-writing-to-macbook-pro-in-target-disk-mode).

Maybe some defect in Ubuntu Firewire driver.

How to fix this?

From [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264103) I find this interesting content:

```
mac2011-linux% more /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-firewire.conf
# Select the legacy firewire stack over the new CONFIG_FIREWIRE one.

blacklist ohci1394
blacklist sbp2
blacklist dv1394
blacklist raw1394
blacklist video1394

#blacklist firewire-ohci
#blacklist firewire-sbp2
```

Not sure how to fiddle this.

Comment: Is /dev/sdb4 an external disk or the internal hard drive?  I/O Errors repeatedly on many many different blocks USUALLY points to disk failure, and if it's the external firewire device then you may hjave to accept that the drive is just dead.  Especially if multiple systems have the same types of errors.  ALSO, note that Firewire is more or less gone the way of the dodo, there's not many people still able to test/fix Firewire drivers now since most Firewire devices have gone away.

Comment: It is an external device, as it is accessed by Firewire,  It is not dead since it has no problem with another enclosure.  Also the problem remains identical with a second device.  The enclosure is not dead since the problem appears on two enclosures of the same type, one brand new.  Remain two solutions : the enclosure has a design flaw (that is not visible with Mac OS) or the Ubuntu Firewire driver has a bug (that is only visible with this enclosure).

Comment: Yes Firewire is very old but still supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: as i stated, Firewire is more or less going the way of the dodo - extinct - most devices don't even *have* Firewire as an option anymore in favor of USB-C or similar.  I know that there's bugs in the Firewire drivers but there's nobody with hardware to debug/test/fix those anymore.  You would need to file this as a bug report, because I'm pretty sure if this is a driver problem it needs far more help than Ask Ubuntu can provide (i.e. someone dedicated to fixing firewire drivers)

Comment: I will think about it. The case is not really crucial as I have many workarounds but I like to understand what is going on.

Comment: I should upgrade to 21.10 also.

Comment: Found this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264103